SearchKit: GroupBy Rows/Columns?
Would it be possible to create a [pivot?] table in SearchKit, where rows are Membership Type(-s) and columns are Membership Statuses, with sum of results in cells? Used to be possible with the Extended  Reports extension by @eileen ( ?) , but it seems to be "close to obsolete" in favour of SearchKit. Would "Data Segmentation" help - can't figure out how it works? Have been poking around and got nowhere so far. The below shows what I have:

And this would be the desired outcome:

